# How to release memory from TF2 graphs when using TFRecordDataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

Sorry if there are any mistakes in this question. I come from a PyTorch background but I need to use `TFRecordDataset` in order to read from `TFRecord`'s. Currently, this looks like the following:

```py
class TFRecordReader:
    def __iter__(self):
        dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(
            [self.tfrecord_path], compression_type="GZIP"
        )
        dataset = dataset.map(self._parse_example)
        self._tfr_iter = iter(dataset)

    def __next__(self):
        return next(self._tfr_iter)
```

However, I need to create multiple `TFRecordReader`'s per PyTorch worker to do batch balancing. This results in me having 4 `TFRecordDataset` (4 buckets to balance with) per worker per GPU, so I end up with 4 * 4 * 4 = 64 `TFRecordDataset` in memory. I have enough CPU memory to do this, but the issue is that the memory is not being released from the `TFRecordDataset` as the memory is increasing consistently over the course of training. I believe the issue is that the computation graph keeps being grown (every time a new `TFRecord` is read a new `TFRecordDataset` is created for it), but is never released.

How can I make sure that the memory used by the `TFRecordDataset` is released after I finish iterating through a single `TFRecord`?

I tried:

```py
def __iter__(self)
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
        dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(
            [self.tfrecord_path], compression_type="GZIP"
        )
        dataset = dataset.map(self._parse_example)

        tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
        self._tfr_iter = iter(dataset)

        while True:
            try:
                example_dict = next(
                    self._tfr_iter
                )
   # ...
```

However, I get an error that:

```py
RuntimeError: __iter__() is only supported inside of tf.function or when eager execution is enabled.
```

I would really appreciate any advice on how to make sure the memory does not keep growing. I am using Tensorflow 2.5 for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be using the PyTorch profiler with PyTorch Lightning. The issue was not with Tensorflow.

See relevant issue [here](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/11480)